# HTACCESS not compressing url page

Tags: .htaccess, magento, compression

I have an issue on my Magento eCommerce http://boligrafopublicidad.es. When I check the site using Google PageSpeed Insights (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=boligrafopublicidad.es&tab=desktop) there are two pages that are not compressed. .JPG images, .JS files, and so on are compressed correctly, but not the main page.

Is there somtehing wrong in the HTACCESS that follows that I should add or change to get the page to be compressed?

```
# HTACCESS created by OB, pending adding Magento Specifics
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Force the latest IE version or ChromeFrame
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
BrowserMatch MSIE ie
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
</IfModule>
</IfModule>


# para comprimir textos, html, javascript, css,y archivos xml:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# O bien comprime los archivos según su extensión:
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

</IfModule>


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Merge js and css will increase performance.

Comment: Are you sure your hosting provider supports mod_deflate? Mine, 1and1, doesn't so I had to use a work around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I merged the css and js and it goes slightly quicker. I will also check the mod_deflate issue with my hosting provider to discard that one. Thanks again.